# actualizar página despues de iniciar sesión

Tags: html, html5, materialize

Hola tengo un sistema de login en un modal; realiza su función correctamente sólo que al cerrar el modal la pagina muestra los cambios relacionados al login, para que los muestre tengo que recargar la página manualmente.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.modal').modal();
 });
```

```css
button {
  background-color: #90a4ae !important;
 }
 button:hover {
  background-color: #eceff1 !important;
  color: #000000 !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
 }
```

```html
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>
  
<nav class="white-text blue-grey lighten-2" role="navigation">
 <div class="nav-wrapper container">
  <a href='#modal1' id='sesion' class='modal-trigger'>Iniciar sesión</a>
 </div>
</nav>
  
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
 <form role="form" id="formLogin" name="formLogin" method="post">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="input-field">
     <i class="fas fa-user prefix"></i>
     <input class="validate" type="text" name="usuario" required>
     <label for="usuario">Ingresa tu correo o usuario</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
     <i class="fas fa-unlock prefix"></i>
     <input class="validate" type="password" name="clave">
     <label for="clave">Ingresa tu contraseña</label>
     <div>
      <label style="float: right;"><a href="#" id="olvido"><b>¿Olvidó su contraseña?</b></a></label><br>
     </div>
    </div>
    <center>
     <div class="row">
      <button type="submit" class="col s12 btn btn-large waves-effect green accent-4">Iniciar sesión</button>
     </div>
    </center>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color:#f1f1f1;">
  <center>
   <a href="#" id="registro" class="btn-flat">¿No tienes cuenta? Regístrate!</a>
  </center>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Al presionar el boton iniciar sesión se muestra el modal y luego que la sesion esté iniciada el boton iniciar sesión deberia mostrar el menú automaticamente sin necesidad de recargar la página manualmente.

Comment: Simplemente has un `location.reload();` en la respuesta positiva de tu login y listo0

Comment: Hola gracias me funcionó fué `window.location.reload(true);`